# Runtime error while reading qmap function of R in juypter note book

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, qmap

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'qmap'

how to resolve the error have tried updating the versions of R in anaconda

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
         21 rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
---> 22 qmap = importr('qmap')
     23 from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
     24 from rpy2.robjects import r
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))